# concurrent.ExecutionException on @service spring bean method

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, concurrency

I have this spring @Service bean:

```
@Service
public class ParMngImpl implements ParMng {

    @Autowired
    private ApplicationContext ctx;

    @Autowired
    private ParDAO pDao;

    //@Transactional(readOnly = true)
    public /*synchronized*/ Double getDbl(Storable st, String cd, Date genDt) {
        Par par = getByCD(cd);
        try {
            for (Dw d: st.getDw()) {
                if (Utl.between(genDt, d.getDt1(), d.getDt2())) {
                    if (d.getPar().equals(par)) {
                        if (d.getPar().getTp().equals("NM")) {
                            if (d.getPar().getDataTp().equals("SI")) {
                                return d.getN1();
                            } else {
                                    throw new WrongGetMethod("Wrong type");
                            }
                        } else {
                            throw new WrongGetMethod("Wrong cd");
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            if (!isExByCd(cd)) {
                throw new WrongGetMethod("Parameter not exists");
            };
        } catch (WrongGetMethod e) {
            //TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }
...
```

This bean is statless (without any instance fields) and it is - singletone.
Why when I remove "synchronized" word, I get this concurrent exception:

```
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(FutureTask.java:122)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:192)
    at com.ric.bill.ChrgServ.chrgLsk(ChrgServ.java:179)
    at com.ric.bill.ChrgServ$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$67dcba28.invoke(<generated>)
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:204)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:651)
    at com.ric.bill.ChrgServ$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$e923e72.chrgLsk(<generated>)
    at com.ric.bill.ChrgServThr.chrgAndSaveLsk(ChrgServThr.java:35)
    at com.ric.bill.ChrgServThr$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$8f447d36.invoke(<generated>)
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:204)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(CglibAopProxy.java:720)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:157)
    at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.AsyncExecutionInterceptor$1.call(AsyncExecutionInterceptor.java:115)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.hibernate.engine.internal.StatefulPersistenceContext.getLoadedCollectionOwnerOrNull(StatefulPersistenceContext.java:780)
    at org.hibernate.event.spi.AbstractCollectionEvent.getLoadedOwnerOrNull(AbstractCollectionEvent.java:58)
    at org.hibernate.event.spi.InitializeCollectionEvent.<init>(InitializeCollectionEvent.java:22)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.initializeCollection(SessionImpl.java:2002)
    at org.hibernate.collection.internal.AbstractPersistentCollection$4.doWork(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:562)
    at org.hibernate.collection.internal.AbstractPersistentCollection.withTemporarySessionIfNeeded(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:246)
    at org.hibernate.collection.internal.AbstractPersistentCollection.initialize(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:558)
    at org.hibernate.collection.internal.AbstractPersistentCollection.read(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:131)
    at org.hibernate.collection.internal.PersistentBag.iterator(PersistentBag.java:277)
    at com.ric.bill.mm.impl.ParMngImpl.getDbl(ParMngImpl.java:65)
    at com.ric.bill.mm.impl.ParMngImpl$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$e246ae1d.invoke(<generated>)
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:204)
```

Also "@Transactional(readOnly = true)" doesn't help me to solve this issue.

I have to say, that my code works well when I use "synchronized", but I don't think this a good solution.

Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Which line is line 65. And let me guess the `Storable` is a hibernate managed entity?

Comment: Line 65 is: for (Dw d: st.getDw()) {   . Yes, Storable is a hibernate entity

Comment: So you are retrieving an object, then execute an async method and pass it an object. You cannot share entities between threads... Retrieve the entity inside that method instead of passing it.

Comment: Can you provide example, how to retrieve entity inside method? Should I do em.find() ?

Comment: Pass the id and find it. That isn't different as other places... It is just a db lookup like you probably do all over the place.

Answer (score 0):

In this line of code I tried to iterate over collection getDw():

for (Dw d: st.getDw()) {

It was incorrect, because this collection couldn't initialize in threads.
So, my solution is before invoking this method, do
st.size() on passed entity, to initialize collection.

It is completly solve my problem.